# how to detect that user has closed not refresh the browser window in Nodejs socket.io

Tags: node.js, disconnect

I am not getting the exact answer of my question.

Many wrote the answer as socket.on('disconnect', function() {}), but it works for both close and refresh.

Any idea?

Comment: I can't imagine there is a difference. When the browser is closed or refreshed the connection is closed on both instances, it is not as if the browser will keep the connection open. Is there some specific behaviour you need to do if refreshed?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a direct answer, but I don't know of a way that socket.io could tell the difference. All it knows is, a user disconnected. Then, half a second later, another user appeared (when the page comes back up again). If you have session identifiers, you could find that it's the same user. I don't know if there are browser events for refresh vs. close.

Comment: Don't create a new question to continue the conversation of a previous question. Just edit the existing question to provide more information for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really possible, because the server doesn't know the difference between a disconnect. All it knows is that the browser closed the connection, it doesn't know why.

However, you could guess which one it was by watching to see if the browser reconnects in a short period of time:

1. Give each client a unique ID that you store somewhere in your
   database, and the browser stores it in localStorage.
2. Have the browser sends the ID when it connects, if it has one, and
   request a new id if it doesn't.
3. On the server, set a short timeout after the client disconnects,
   maybe 3 seconds.
4. If you see a new connection with the same ID during that timeout, then
   you can assume it was a refresh. If you don't see a new connection
   with the same ID, you can assume the browser window (or tab) was
   closed.

However, this ads some complexity to your app and probably isn't worth the trouble unless you *really* need to know when a user hits refresh.

Comment: I really need to distinguish between two.I think it should work.